# Rename linked resource programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

I an new to Eclipse Plugin Development and I am trying to rename my linked file.
I have created a linked file in Eclipse as below:

```
IFile myLinkedFile = folder.getFile(originalFileName);  
myLinkedFile.createLink(myabsolutePath, IResource.NONE, null);
```

This works like a charm.

However, now I would like to rename `myLinkedFile` without changing the name of the original File. Just like the behavior of pressing F2 or by the Rename from the context menu that appears on right clicking the liked file.

I am trying to achieve renaming using `move()`

```
originalFile.move(newPath, IResource.FORCE, null);
```

However it always throws

> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException

...and complains about my `newPath`. Can someone tell me what is wrong in my approach and how do I do it right?

My original file is a text file located at `C:/Temp/originalFile.txt`. I would like to rename the file to `newFile.txt` in my workspace. The exception says invalid path. For the `newPath` I have specified as `C:/Temp/newFile.txt`

---

In the below example the original files is located in the resources folder of my project
Here I am creating a new folder called myTextFiles. This folder will contain the linked files.
After creating the linked files I am trying to rename the linked files.

```
IFolder folder = myCurrentProject.getFolder("myTextFiles");  
folder.create(IResource.REPLACE, true, null);  

IFile file = folder.getFile(absoluteLocation); //absolute location of folder containing images  
file.createLink(absoluteLocation, IResource.REPLACE, null);  
folder.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);            


String myNewFileName = "newFile.txt";  
IFile myLinkedFile = folder.getFile(myNewFileName);  
IPath newPath = new Path(myNewFileName);  

IFile movedFile = folder.getFile(newFileName);  
movedFile.createLink(newPath, IResource.NONE, null);  

folder.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
```

Comment: What is `originalFile` here? What is the value of `newPath` and what exactly does the exception say?

Comment: my original file is a text file located at C:/Temp/originalFile.txt. I would like to rename the file to newFile.txt. The exception says invalid path. For the newPath I have specified as C:/Temp/newFile.txt

Comment: This is still not clear. You can only use `move` to move a resource in the workspace. The path must be a full path in the workspace ('/project/folder/file'). You can't use this to rename the file it links to,

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I do not want to rename the physical file. I just want the name to be shown as newFile.txt in my workspace. The physical file will still have the name original.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `move` to move the resource to a new location in the Eclipse workspace.

The path you specify for `move` must be a path relative to the root of the Eclipse workspace or relative to the current resource location - often just a file name.

So

```
IPath newPath = new Path("/project/folder/newFile.txt");
```

or

```
IPath newPath = new Path("newFile.txt");
```

Paths starting with '/' are relative to the workspace root (known as a 'absolute' path), anything else is relative to the current resource folder.

Paths in the Eclipse workspace never use "C:/"

Comment: Sorry. It still throws org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Cannot create linked resource.  Local location does not exist.   Can you give an example of renaming the linked resource without changing the name of the physical file

Comment: As far as I can see it is only `createLink` that produces that message. Show us a proper [mcve] and the stack trace.

Comment: I get the same error :  org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Cannot create linked resource. Local location does not exist. Is it necessary the location path folder must exist in disk file system ? Can't we give a non existing IPath location ? Is it non-sense ?

Comment: @ilkeMuhtaroglu Ask a new question showing a [mcve]

Comment: movedFile.createLink(newPath, IResource.NONE, null);  
here instead of  IResource.NONE calling the method with IResource.ALLOW_MISSING_LOCAL does the job for me.